# Flex objects not recognized using QTP

Tags: apache-flex, automation, qtp

I have to automate a Flex application using QTP 10. Object spy is showing 'MacromediaFlashPlayer' for all the objects in the application.

Does this mean the application is not automation friendly. Do I have to ask something from developers to add ??

Any help will be highly appreciated !

Answer (score 1):

Testing Using QTP:

1. Install `QTP_plugin` for flex. This can be found in install directory of flex.
2. Include the following libraries in the compiler arguments.

Include libraries:

- "C:\Program Files\Adobe\Flex Builder 3\sdks\3.5.0\frameworks\libs\automation.swc"
- "C:\Program Files\Adobe\Flex Builder 3\sdks\3.5.0\frameworks\libs\automation_agent.swc"
- "C:\Program Files\Adobe\Flex Builder 3\sdks\3.5.0\frameworks\libs\qtp.swc"
- "C:\Program Files\Adobe\Flex Builder 3\sdks\3.5.0\frameworks\libs\automation_dmv.swc"

and you are good to go.

Remember, those components, which has `ChildMouse` property set to `false`, will be shown in the testing as `MacroMediaFlashPlayerActiveX` object.